# Why doesn't my array in ng-repeat re-render after I add an item?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a menu and an order tab. When clicked on an "Add" button on the menu item it should add this item to an order. The order tab must be updated, and it should update automatically in Angular as far as I can see in the web. But it doesn't in my case. Here's my html:

```
<div class="order-bar" ng-controller="menuCtrl">
  <div class="order-bar-toggle"></div>
  <h2>Your order:</h2>
   <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in order">
      <p>{{item.name}}, {{item.price}}.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Menu:</h1>
</div>

<div ng-controller="menuCtrl">

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="meal in menu">
      {{meal.name}}, {{meal.price}}. Description: {{meal.description}}. <button ng-click="addToOrder(meal)">Add</button>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

and js file:

```
var menuApp = angular.module("menuApp", []);

menuApp.controller("menuCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.menu = [
    {name: "Coca-Cola", category: "Soft Drink", description: "Carbonated Soda Drink", price: "6 zl", vegetarian: true, image: "Coca-Cola.jpg"},
    {name: "Nestea", category: "Soft Drink", description: "Iced Tea Drink", price: "6 zl", vegetarian: true, image: "nestea.jpg"},
    {name: "Frankfurt Sausages", category: "Main Dish", description: "With ketchup, mustard and french fries", price: "27 zl", vegetarian: false, image: "Sausages.jpg"},
    {name: "Ice Cream", category: "Dessert", description: "Vanilla, Chocolate, Strawberry, Stracciatella", price: "13 zl", vegetarian: false, image: "icecream.jpg"},
    {name: "Brownie", category: "Dessert", description: "Chocolate Cake", price: "15 zl", vegetarian: false, image: "Brownie.jpg"}
  ];

  $scope.order = [{name: "product", price:"1000 zl"}];

  $scope.addToOrder = function(meal) {
    $scope.order.push(meal);
    console.log($scope.order);
  }

});
```

When I console.log my updated order it shows new elements in it but they don't get printed out on the page. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing **`</div>`** in the html, also no need to have two menuCtrl, have one for the entire  change it like below.

When you set the controller again , it will get reinitialized.

```js
var menuApp = angular.module("menuApp", []);

menuApp.controller("menuCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.menu = [
    {name: "Coca-Cola", category: "Soft Drink", description: "Carbonated Soda Drink", price: "6 zl", vegetarian: true, image: "Coca-Cola.jpg"},
    {name: "Nestea", category: "Soft Drink", description: "Iced Tea Drink", price: "6 zl", vegetarian: true, image: "nestea.jpg"},
    {name: "Frankfurt Sausages", category: "Main Dish", description: "With ketchup, mustard and french fries", price: "27 zl", vegetarian: false, image: "Sausages.jpg"},
    {name: "Ice Cream", category: "Dessert", description: "Vanilla, Chocolate, Strawberry, Stracciatella", price: "13 zl", vegetarian: false, image: "icecream.jpg"},
    {name: "Brownie", category: "Dessert", description: "Chocolate Cake", price: "15 zl", vegetarian: false, image: "Brownie.jpg"}
  ];

  $scope.order = [{name: "product", price:"1000 zl"}];

  $scope.addToOrder = function(meal) {
    $scope.order.push(meal);
    console.log($scope.order);
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 
</head>
<body ng-app='menuApp'>
  <div class="order-bar" ng-controller="menuCtrl">
   <h2>Your order:</h2>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in order">
      <p>{{item.name}}, {{item.price}}.</p>
    </li>
 </ul>
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Menu:</h1>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="meal in menu">
      {{meal.name}}, {{meal.price}}. Description: {{meal.description}}.
      <button ng-click="addToOrder(meal)">Add</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wait, I can't find where I'm missing an '>'. I have it in <div class="order-bar" ng-controller="menuCtrl">, don't I?

Comment: @AlexanderDonets what i meant was, place the </div> outside , also remove the other controll, since it will get reinitialized

Comment: ohh I see now, thanks! Another question: if I want to go to another page and use my current order array there, how can I save its value? It gets cleared every time I reload the page...

Comment: @AlexanderDonets you need to use service/factory to store the values

Comment: Thanks! Will check it out

Comment: @AlexanderDonets why did you  remove the answer/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129827/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-alexander-donets).

Comment: I didn't. What's happened?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have 2 controller instances on your page. You are adding the items to the orders of one controller scope, but displaying them from another.

If you are going to repeat on that array, you will also need to add a track by to the repeat to prevent errors on duplicates.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/BubbleHulk/858ejwuv/) is an example.

```
<div ng-app="menuApp">

<div class="order-bar" ng-controller="menuCtrl">
  <div class="order-bar-toggle"></div>
  <h2>Your order:</h2>
   <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in order track by $index">
      <p>{{item.name}}, {{item.price}}.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Menu:</h1>
</div>


  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="meal in menu">
      {{meal.name}}, {{meal.price}}. Description: {{meal.description}}. <button ng-click="addToOrder(meal)">Add</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


</div>
```